# What is the difference between Solutions and Services in networking?

Tags: knowledgebase

In the network terms we often hear about The solutions and services. I want to know what is the difference between them? and How we categorized network related functions under these two titles?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you have anything you could reference in the terms solutions and services? Like an article or something you read?

Comment: We often see in companie's websites that refer to solutions and services for customers. for example network infrastructure, VOIP, security, etc. What are these? Solutions or services?

Comment: A solution actually solves a specific problem or set of problems. A service can be part of a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solutions could be a Network specifically designed for your organization or company. A complete network (plug and play) that supports your needs with up-to-date standards, features and securities. Solutions could also be smaller parts of that, for instance, if you only need VoIP for your company, then you can buy a plug and play VoIP solution.

A network service is an application running at the network application layer and above, that provides data storage, manipulation, presentation, communication or other capability which is often implemented using a client-server or peer-to-peer architecture based on application layer network protocols.

You could say, that a network solution is the infrastructure that you implement your network service on.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is more technical. Can you explain these from Business point of view?

Comment: You want to sell a network solution, which includes physical network devices like switches, routers, firewalls, etc. The solution also includes the physical installation and knowhow from network administrators. Then after that you would like to sell network services, like storage to the same people who just bought the solution. I hope that might make more sense.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. In the other words we can say the Solution is when you design and Implement and the Service starts after that. Is this true?

Comment: Yes. Services can be sold/implemented after the solution is designed and implemented.